How to extract a RAR file that is bigger than my free space
I have a 118GB RAR file when extracted becomes 200GB, and I only have 150GB free space on my computer.
I have tried to extract some and delete some from the RAR file, but deleting from a RAR file requires the winRAR program to make a temp file equal to the size of the unselected part of the RAR file.
I searched for a way to split the RAR file but had no luck in that, the only way I found requires more storage and doesn't delete the original RAR.
And I don't think there is a website that can extract the file for me and download it as folders.
The only solution is to get more space, I don't want that, is there any other workaround?

There are a bunch of ways around it. What I would do:

Extract a few files/folders.
Upload them to a service like Sendspace, MEGA or Google Drive. Make sure to store them privately to avoid any copyright issues in case they concern your files. And if you didn't find cloud storage big enough, store the files on multiple.
Delete the uploaded files and repeat steps 1-3 until the whole RAR is done.
Delete the RAR archive.
Download the files/folders that you need. Remove them from the cloud if they are copyrighted, just in case.


I don't really agree with this option. We're talking about 150GB of extracted data here. That is a really long time of uploading files to the internet. And a 150GB archive might be a game or movie which may be against the terms of service of online services, which may mean that they terminate your account. Also, Google Drive can't hold 150GB without paying. Not sure about the other two, but I think they have limitations too.

Really long time is nonsense - you don't know their upload speed or anything. On any modern internet it would be done in a matter of hours max, without risking running out of space like in your only solution 4 that meets author's requirements. Copyright law and ToS is much more valid issue, but I don't think anyone would care as long as you use the files privately and don't share them. MEGA definitely doesn't have any automatic file scanning, not sure about Google, but you would delete the files after a bit anyways.

I'd say banning for temporary storage in cloud would be in fact absurd, as moving something copyrighted to autosynced folder accidentally is quite possible and would completely piss off users of such services.

If you were to put it on the remote storage for a day, and then remove it again to fix your accident, of course you're not going to get banned. But 150GB is not going to be uploaded to cloud storage in a few hours. That'll take days. Especially given you're suggesting to do it in chunks. So it will probably take a week.

Free MEGA is now limited to 20GB and there are additional quota limits per day. Terabox could be an option - free 1TB - but it's cumbersome, has annoying adds popping up, and the free plan is very slow.

Deleting portion of the winRAR will not work, because to delete a portion, the program have to make a temp copy of all the unselected portion before deleting, this because the file is compressed and all the data are related.

I never mentioned deleting portion of RAR...

Sorry misunderstood you, thanks that would work.

You will need more free space. This can be from an external disk, or free space on a different partition. You do not need 200GB of free space though. About 55 GB is enough. Just enough free space to completely extract the RAR file.
There are multiple ways you can go about doing this.

Move files from your main drive to a temporary storage place on other drives to increase the free space available on the drive you want to extract the RAR file.

Extract a part of the RAR file to other storage areas, and do this until you have extracted all of the RAR file somewhere else. Then delete the RAR file, and move all the extracted pieces back to the same location to reconstruct the content of the RAR file.


The second method is prone to making mistakes, so the first option is preferred if possible.

Get a large enough storage to hold the entire RAR file and directly extract to that drive.

Cumbersome method, but could be what you want.
Extract a small portion of the RAR file, then create a new RAR file with those files, then delete the extracted files. Do this until all of the main content of the large RAR files have been duplicated into smaller RAR files. You should have about 130 GB of smaller RAR files and the large one. Then delete the large RAR file. Now you can extract each smaller RAR file and delete that RAR file. Note, this method is also prone to failure. If you miss a file it will be gone.



I don't want to add extra storage, and I will not delete any other file from my device, is there any workaround other than that.

Then option 4 is the only way.

Deleting portion of the winRAR will not work, because to delete a portion, the program have to make a temp copy of all the unselected portion before deleting, this because the file is compressed and all the data are related.

I'm sorry, you misunderstood me. You extract a few files from the big rar file. You create a new rar file from the few files you extracted. You delete the files you extracted. You now have the big rar file and a smaller one. Repeat these steps until all the files have been extracted and then a new rar file was created for the small files. At the end, you will have one large rar file and a lot of smaller rar files with the same content. You can now safely delete the large rar file. After that, you can extract the smaller rar files one at a time, and delete the rarfile, but keep the extracted.

I understood you, you said "You delete the files you extracted" and I am telling you: YOU CAN'T because the winRAR app have to make a temp file copying all the data that you don't want to delete then it can delete the data from the rar file.

What happens if you try to extract a single file using 7zip? Maybe rar can't do it, but maybe 7zip can extract a single file from the rar file.
